# Generating hillshade from different ranged rasters

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh

I have nine digital elevation model raster files in 16 bit unsigned TIF format from which I'm trying to generate hillshade. The reason for this is that my computer isn't powerful enough for Blender to tackle only one or two files.

Everything works as expected and I'm very happy with the results, but only when I tried to merge them I realized that they look different.

[image]

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that each TIF has a different value range than the other eight. For example 1.TIF has `0 - 39961` and 2.TIF has `9791 - 40104`.

I am using a node-based shading:

[image]

Using these files, is there anything I can do to generate hillshades that have the same value range so they don't look inappropriate when merged together?

Comment: Are you displacing geometry with a modifier or with shading nodes? Could you tell why the images have different value ranges?

Comment: You can try to normalize the values 1-0 by letting the input through color ramp or smth.

Comment: @Carlo I am using node-based shading. The image have different value ranges because they were created separately in the first place.

Comment: @Mzidare I don't quite understand your advice. How do I normalize them?

Comment: Could you show your current nodetree? Did you already used the Math node to alter the values? What's going wrong?

Comment: @Carlo I edited the question to add the nodetree. I didn't use Math since I thought I got the results that I wanted, but also I'm not sure how and if to use it.

Comment: With math node you can perform mathematical operations on the incoming data. It can be helpful in re-parametrizing values. Apart from that, most common Image color space for displacement texture is "Non-Color Data, instead of "Color". Is there a reason behind your choiche? Did you tried to use "Non-Color Data"?

Comment: @CezarB For some reason I initially assumed that when you wrote “different value range” you meant that the tiles all map from black to white but in each tile black to white maps to a different height in meters. Now I realize that you meant intensity values. In this case my answer doesn't help. Sorry.

Comment: By normalizing I meant to turn any value range to 0-1. This way, if the ranges are the same (f.ex. 10) but reaches from different number to another different number (like from 0 to 10 and the other from 10 to 20) you'll get output values reaching from  0 to1 no matter what initial values are.